# Multi level inheritance

Tags: c++

I'm transferring from Java and I'm trying to learn how to write a good code in C++.

I have a question according to a multi level inheritance from the **abstract classes**

I have this pseudocode in Java and I want to define the similar structure using class interfaces in C++ with all the constructors and destructors.

```
abstract class Node {
    public abstract void addChild(Node child);
}

abstract class StmtNode extends Node {

}

class WhileNode extends StmtNode {

}
```

My question is: Can you help me define such classes?

@edit
Currently I have the following classes:

```
class Node {
public:
    explicit Node();
    virtual ~Node() = 0;

    virtual void addChild(Node* child) = 0;
};

class StmtNode : public Node {
public:
    explicit StmtNode();
    virtual ~StmtNode() = 0;

    virtual void addChild(Node* child) override;
};

class WhileNode : StmtNode {
public:
    explicit WhileNode();
    ~WhileNode() override;


    void addChild(Node* child) override;
};
```

Are they correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just remove all the Java keywords and add the appropriate C++ syntax. A nice tutorial can do miracles.

Comment: @drescherjm updated

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to define parameter less ctor as `explicit`. 
So `explicit Node();` can be simplified by removing `explicit` keyword;

Don't forget to provide an implementation for pure virtual destruction otherwise you will have undefined behavior in your code.

```
inline Node::~Node() { }
inline StmtNode::~StmtNode() { }
```

Because `Node` and `StmtNode` have a pure virtual function and act like an `interface` you can define their `ctors` as protected.

There is no need to define `destruction`s with `override` keyword.